# How Do I remove video playback on my iPhone 7 completely?

Tags: iphone, settings

Hi I want to completely disable the ability to play videos on my iPhone. I don't mind jailbreaking the phone to change some core settings if this is the solution. I'm not just not sure what to change. Thank you.

iPhone 7 OS 12.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the OS version.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Comment: Added the OS. I basically want to know if it is possible to change core setting to stop videos from playing?

Comment: No it is not possible. If you jailbreak? No idea, that would be best asked on jailbreaking forums.

Comment: Do you want to stop them from playing automatically or at all?

Comment: Are you talking about video games?

Comment: At all, and not just video games, any video playback

Comment: Can I ask why? We might be able to give you a better answer if we know what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Screen Time in Settings and you could allow the apps you want or need and keep the ones you don't want out. 
Also in Screen Time settings under Content & Privacy Restrictions you can turn off or restrick settings. You can choose to not allow apps. You can choose Don't allow Movies and scroll down to the bottom and turn off Show movies in the Cloud.